# NativeScript & Angular - How to clear the router history?

Tags: angular, nativescript, router

I am working on a NativeScript 6 project with Angular 8.

I want to clear the router history after the user logs in.

This is what I've tried:

public onLogin() {

```
this.registerUserCredentialsService
    .registerUserCredentials(this.username, this.password)
    .then(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['home-page'], { clearHistory: true });
    });
```

}

I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR in src/app/register-user-credentials.component.ts(33,55): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ clearHistory: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NavigationExtras'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'clearHistory' does not exist in type 'NavigationExtras'.
How can I clear the router history?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NativeScript < 7.0**

Try using `RouterExtensions` instead of `Router`

```js
import { RouterExtensions } from "nativescript-angular/router";

...
constructor(
  private routerExtensions: RouterExtensions
) {}
...
this.routerExtensions.navigate(['home-page'], { clearHistory: true });
```

**NativeScript > 7.0**

`RouterExtensions` has a different import path in more recent NativeScript versions (it's usage is still the same)

```js
import { RouterExtensions } from "@nativescript/angular";

...
constructor(
  private routerExtensions: RouterExtensions
) {}
...
this.routerExtensions.navigate(['home-page'], { clearHistory: true });
```

Comment: Argument of type '{ clearHistory: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NavigationExtras'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'clearHistory' does not exist in type 'NavigationExtras'

Comment: `clearHistory`  is part of `ExtendedNavigationExtras`. It doesn't exist in `NavigationExtras` @Satrughna

Answer (score -1):

you may also use queryParams as the mentioned in documentation for router options [Angular NavigationExtras](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras). You can set up like this one.

```
this.router.navigate(['home-page'], {queryParams: {clearHistory: true }});
```